# Fast String Array (Individual) Hashing in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

As the title suggests, I would love some suggestions on how to make the following code faster. I have tried multiple methods including utilizing Numba, a combination of the `np.fromiter()` and `map()` functions, as well as Numpy vectorizing the hash function so as to get it all to work faster.

Take a look at the code below! Below the code are the results of the code from running it on my machine.

Some notes for the future:

- the `CODES` variable holds the dimensions of the arrays that need to be hashed (generated random strings for StackOverflow purposes)
- the first compilation time for Numba is quite high, but I am willing to take on this cost if it means speeding up the code in the long run when running hundreds of thousands of times

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb
import time

# GENERATE RANDOM "<U64" CHARACTER ARRAYS
A, Z = np.array(["A","Z"]).view("int32") 

CODES = (25058, 64272, 61425)
LENGTH = 64

tmp1 = np.random.randint(low = A, high = Z, size = CODES[0] * LENGTH, dtype = "int32").view(f"U{LENGTH}")
tmp2 = np.random.randint(low = A, high = Z, size = CODES[1] * LENGTH, dtype = "int32").view(f"U{LENGTH}")
tmp3 = np.random.randint(low = A, high = Z, size = CODES[2] * LENGTH, dtype = "int32").view(f"U{LENGTH}")

# NUMBA ITERATION AND HASHING ONE BY ONE
@nb.jit(nopython=True, fastmath=True, parallel=True, cache=True)
def form_hashed_array(to_hash: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    hashed = np.empty_like(to_hash, dtype=np.int64)

    for i in nb.prange(len(to_hash)):
        hashed[i] = hash(to_hash[i])

    return hashed

print("--------")
t2 = time.monotonic()

t = time.monotonic()
tmp4 = form_hashed_array(tmp1)
print(time.monotonic() - t) # this first one will be larger due to compilation time

t = time.monotonic()
tmp5 = form_hashed_array(tmp2)
print(time.monotonic() - t)

t = time.monotonic()
tmp6 = form_hashed_array(tmp3)
print(time.monotonic() - t)

print("NUMBA ITERATION TOOK: " + str(time.monotonic() - t2))

# MAP + FROMITER COMBINATION
print("--------")
t2 = time.monotonic()

t = time.monotonic()
tmp7 = np.fromiter((map(hash, tmp1)), dtype=np.int64)
print(time.monotonic() - t)

t=time.monotonic()
tmp8 = np.fromiter((map(hash, tmp2)), dtype=np.int64)
print(time.monotonic()-t)

t = time.monotonic()
tmp9 = np.fromiter((map(hash, tmp3)), dtype=np.int64)
print(time.monotonic()-t)

print("MAP + FROMITER COMBINATION TOOK : " + str(time.monotonic()-t2))

# NUMPY FUNCTION VECTORIZATION
vfunc = np.vectorize(hash)

print("--------")
t2 = time.monotonic()

t = time.monotonic()
tmp10 = vfunc(tmp1)
print(time.monotonic() - t)

t = time.monotonic()
tmp11 = vfunc(tmp2)
print(time.monotonic() - t)

t = time.monotonic()
tmp12 = vfunc(tmp3)
print(time.monotonic() - t)

print("NUMPY FUNCTION VECTORIZATION TOOK: " + str(time.monotonic()-t2))

# SANITY CHECKS
print("--------")
print(not (tmp4 - tmp7).any() and not (tmp7 - tmp10).any(), end=" ")
print(not (tmp5 - tmp8).any() and not (tmp8 - tmp11).any(), end=" ")
print(not (tmp6 - tmp9).any() and not (tmp9 - tmp12).any())
print("--------")

breakpoint()
```

This code will be run a significant number of times, so it is important that it is as fast as possible.

```
--------
6.9208437809720635
0.08914285799255595
0.09502507897559553
NUMBA ITERATION TOOK: 7.1051117710303515
--------
0.009926816972438246
0.02683716599131003
0.026946138008497655
MAP + FROMITER COMBINATION TOOK : 0.06381386297289282
--------
0.011753249040339142
0.02864329604199156
0.029279633017722517
NUMPY FUNCTION VECTORIZATION TOOK: 0.06976548000238836
--------
True True True
--------
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: So you want to hash a list of strings?

Comment: Yes, I would like a very fast method to hash large lists of strings. The map function does it very quickly when I tried. I'm just unsure of other ways to get the values afterwards apart from `np.fromiter()` and converting it into a list which take up a majority of the time.

Comment: `map` just sets things up, `list(map(...))` does the actual work.

Comment: Ahh, yes that's what I had suspected. Do you have any advice on how I can perform "the actual work" faster? I was thinking about potentially converting to bytes and messing around with it that way?

Comment: Note that Numba barely supports strings and they are currently computed very slowly. There is unfortunately no short-term plan to optimize that AFAIK. Calling `np.fromiter(map(hash, ...), ...)` is a bit slow but this is mainly due to CPython string that are unicode one and the interpreter. Using a very recent version of CPython could help a bit but the best is simply to write that in C. Note that working on ASCII string in C can be far faster (eg. one order of magnitude if properly optimized).

Comment: @JérômeRichard What exactly are you referring to in regards to "properly optimizing the code" in C? I replicated the code in C and was about to get a 7x speedup taking it down to ~0.0155s for all three arrays. Is there a way I can make this even faster in a way that I'm unaware of? I used the following for my hash function [link](http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/hash.html).

Comment: @jakubbester For example, using SIMD instructions or taking care that the compiler generate good SIMD instruction for this case (assuming strings are long enough). If the whole program is in C, you can optimize allocations so accesses are contiguous. If the input is big, you can hash the strings in parallel. Lookup tables and low-level instructions can also often help to optimize the computation. As for the hash, your link seems quite old so there is certainly a faster hash function since but note that the quality of the hash may also matter and good ones tends to be slower.

Comment: @jakubbester See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions#Non-cryptographic_hash_functions. MurmurHash is pretty famous and AFAIK fast while being relatively reliable (and I think it can be easily vectorized if needed too).